# How to return inside a loop

Tags: java

I have a program where I need to get a return from a method, the problem is that he always returns the first position and nothing more. This is my method where I want to receive the inputs.

```
  public void getCountByArea() {


              //always receive the same string
              String inputToValidate = getInputsTxtFromConsole();
              String inputToCompare = getInputsTxtFromConsole();


}
```

This is my other method

```
public String getInputsTxtFromConsole() {

//read inputs file
    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

        //read the file line by line
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;

            return line; //this always returns the same number

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


    }


  return "";

}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you understand what `return` does? Its purpose is to end the function and return a value. If you don't want to end the function execution, you shouldn't use `return` there.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? By returning from inside a loop, you remove the need for a loop at all.

Comment: Did you mean to add the lines to a list or something and return the list? You'll need to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: you only can return a value using return statement, you will need to stack all values ​​and then return

Comment: I suggest that you step away from your computer and write **in words** the steps you want to take to solve the problem. The English (or whatever language you use) description will suggest how to structure your Java program to perform the task correctly.

Comment: You're returning line instead lineNum? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to get the values in the getInputsTxtFromConsole() one by one

Answer (score 3):

You can't use return statement to get more of one value because it end the function call. the best way is stack the values and then return. this is a example using arraylist.

```
public List getInputsTxtFromConsole() {

//read inputs file
    try {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList(); //list instance
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

        //read the file line by line
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(scanner.nextLine()); //adding elements
            lineNum++;
        }

    return lines; //then return
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


    }


  return null;

}
```

> SECOND EDIT

if you want to get each value you need to loop the returned list;

```
  public void getCountByArea() {


    //always receive the same string
    List<String> inputToValidate = getInputsTxtFromConsole();
    List<String> inputToCompare = getInputsTxtFromConsole();


    for(String input1 : inputToValidate){ //input1 is a temp variable
        // your custom implementation
        ...
    }
    //another for each
    ...

}
```

Comment: Yeah and in my getCountByArea how can I get the inputs one by one? Note that those strings in that method are inside a while loop(not shown in my code)